# How to get Export buttons, records per page and serach textbox in a single horizontal row in jQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi am using jQuery datatables.

I want all export buttons, records per page and search textbox in a single row above the table something like as shown below.

[image]

But I am getting the below output:-

[image]

I am using below function:-

```
 $(".mydataTable").dataTable({
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayLength": 5,
                 bJQueryUI: true,
                "aLengthMenu": [[-1, 5, 10, 20, 50], ["All", 5, 10, 20, 50]],
                dom: 'Bflit',                
                buttons: [
                  'copyHtml5',
                  'excelHtml5',
                  'csvHtml5',
                  'pdfHtml5'
                ]
            });
```

What should be the dom option for required result?

Comment: i know that but I am asking if there is any dom option that would be better

Comment: try `dom: 'Blfrtip',` , refer : https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Comment: no its not working @OranavCBalan

Comment: Pranav has pointed you in right direction @SunilChaudhry. You can use custom div like given in above link and apply your own CSS to that div.
Something like - dom : '<"myleftdiv"pi>l<"myrightdiv"f>'. Then u will need to add CSS classes for myleftdiv and myrightdiv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using bootstrap (which from your screenshot it looks like you are), try out this dom option:

```
dom:"<'row'<'col-sm-6'b><'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>"
```

Use the DataTables `dom` documentation found [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) (also posted by Pranav in the comments of your question) to get more info if you want to precisely position things. This should, however, put buttons on the same row as the search and records per page items.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative if, you would be interested check the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    lengthMenu: [
        [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
        [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all' ]
    ],
    buttons: [
        'pageLength'
    ]
  });
});
```

You can check the reference [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/pageLength.html)